# When using abstract classes in C#, does AgressiveInlining do anything, and where should it be placed?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, compiler-optimization, jit

Suppose I have an abstract class and a class that implements it.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void Outer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            Inner();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void Inner();
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void Inner()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Since `Outer()` calls `Inner()` so much and does little else, I'd like `Inner()` to be inline'd using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void Outer() // ...

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    protected abstract void Inner();
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    protected override void Inner()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Does this attribute go in `BaseClass`, `MyClass`, or both, or does the attribute not work at all in this case?

Comment: Inner() cannot be inlined, it is abstract.  That always requires a virtual call to the concrete implementation method, implemented as an indirect call though the method table.  Inlining is only possible when the jitter knows which call is going to made at jit time, before the code start running.

Answer (score 1):

Per Hans's comment, abstract members cannot be inline'd due to the nature of abstract classes and virtual calls.

**Edit**: per Ben's comment below, this is not true in general for all compilers, but it is true of JIT (which happened to be the context of my particular question).

Comment: That's not true, devirtualization is a well-known optimization.  It simply is an optimization that the .NET JIT does not implement in this scenario.